# SMOTE to balance over 200 classes in R

Tags: r, resampling, oversampling

I have a two column dataset (feature and class) with over 200 classes to which the input features has to be classified. The occurrence of the classes ranges from 1 to few thousands for some classes. The features column has text and numbers. I tried the below way:

### SMOTE from UBL

```
SmoteClassif(lab ~ ., dat, C.perc = "balance",dist="HEOM")
```

This gives the warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: SmoteClassif :: Nr of examples is less or equal to k.
 Using k = 1 in the nearest neighbours computation in this bump.
2: SmoteClassif :: Nr of examples is less or equal to k.
 Using k = 1 in the nearest neighbours computation in this bump.
3: SmoteClassif :: Nr of examples is less or equal to k.
 Using k = 2 in the nearest neighbours computation in this bump.
4: SmoteClassif :: Nr of examples is less or equal to k.
 Using k = 2 in the nearest neighbours computation in this bump.
```

But still this nicely balances all the classes `lab` equally. However, not all features are present in the SMOTED dataset. Isn't this loss of data i.e features are missing which are required to train the model? I am a novice in this field. Does the warnings explain the problem? I have tried with `k=1` and still the end result is same.

Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 3):

The SmoteClassif function implemented in UBL package **combines oversampling** using the SMOTE procedure **with random undersampling**.

This means that when you use the option "balance", the function will generate new cases for the rarest classes and will remove cases from the most populated classes. The goal, in the end, is to obtain a new balanced data set that has roughly the same size as the original data set. So when you use option "balance" you will generate new synthetic cases and will remove cases from the most frequent classes so that you end up with a data set with a size similar to the initial one.

If you want to apply only the oversampling procedure, then you will need to specify in the C.perc parameter how much oversample you want to apply to each class.
For instance, you can set

```
C.perc = list(A = 2, B=3)
```

This will duplicate the elements of class A and triplicate the elements of class B while the remaining data set is unchanged (all other classes maintain their frequency). In this case your data set is enlarged by the new synthetic and no information is discarded!

A simple example:

```
library(MASS)
data(cats)
table(cats$Sex)

F  M  
47 97 

# class M is duplicated
mysmote.cats <- SmoteClassif(Sex~., cats, list(M = 2))
table(mysmote.cats$Sex)

F   M 
 47 194 

#class M is oversampled by 150% and class F is undersampled by 50%
mysmote.cats <- SmoteClassif(Sex~., cats, list(M = 1.5, F=0.5))
table(mysmote.cats$Sex)

F   M 
 23 145
```

**Regarding the warnings**, the default of the function is to use k=5 when computing the nearest neighbors of the examples from one specific class. However, in some data sets it is not possible to compute the selected number of neighbors because there aren't enough examples. For instance if you only have 3 examples of class A when you select a case from this class you will be able to find at most 2 nearest neighbors from that class!

So, when the number k selected is too large to determine that specific number of neighbors of a case a warning is shown.